# very long runs times with sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier using log loss function

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am attempting to replicate the work done [here](https://github.com/jgcorliss/lending-club/blob/master/predicting_chargeoff.ipynb):

The goal of this project is to build a logistic machine learning model to predict the probability that an investment will fail or not.

The sklearn part of the code is as follows:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer, StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

pipeline_sgdlogreg = Pipeline([
    ('imputer', Imputer(copy=False)), # Mean imputation by default
    ('scaler', StandardScaler(copy=False)),
    ('model', SGDClassifier(loss='log', max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3, random_state=1, warm_start=True))
])


param_grid_sgdlogreg = {
    'model__alpha': [10**-5, 10**-2, 10**1],
    'model__penalty': ['l1', 'l2']
}

grid_sgdlogreg = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipeline_sgdlogreg, param_grid=param_grid_sgdlogreg, 
                              scoring='roc_auc', n_jobs=-1, pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', cv=5, 
                              verbose=1, return_train_score=False)
grid_sgdlogreg.fit(X_train, y_train)

GridSearchCV(cv=5, error_score='raise',
       estimator=Pipeline(memory=None,
       steps=[('imputer', Imputer(axis=0, copy=False, missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', verbose=0)), 
              ('scaler', StandardScaler(copy=False, with_mean=True, with_std=True)), 
              ('model', SGDClassifier(alpha=0.0001, average=False, class_weight=None, epsilon=0.1,
       penalty='l2', power_t=0.5, random_state=1, shuffle=True,
       tol=0.001, verbose=0, warm_start=True))]),
       fit_params=None, iid=True, n_jobs=-1,
       param_grid={'model__alpha': [1e-05, 0.01, 10], 'model__penalty': ['l1', 'l2']},
       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', refit=True, return_train_score=False,
       scoring='roc_auc', verbose=1)
grid_sgdlogreg.best_score_
grid_sgdlogreg.best_params_
```

I have about 200000 rows of data in the training set. An initial run produced no results or messages after 6 hours.

Reducing my training set to 100 rows, the model runs in about 9 seconds. 200 rows seems to run endlessly.

In the python notebook example I am attempting to replicate, the training set had 730000 rows and the run took only 3.3 minutes.

I am running in parallel on an 8 core i7 with 16 gb of ram.

I am guessing I need to do additional pre-processing to data, but don't know where to start. What things should I look for in my data that may cause this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think reducing the `SGDClassifier`'s `max_iter` param value to somewhere in the range `(10,30)` could be a good option to try since you have a large enough dataset for a binary classification, you dont have to do 1000 number of iterations.